# Calling the same imports onto a single cypress file

Tags: javascript, cypress

We are using Cypress v10 and our **.cy.js** files always use these same imports:

```
import Customers from "../imports/Customer"
import Search from "../imports/Search"
import PostComment from "../imports/PostComment"
import Feedback from "../imports/Feedback"
import Login from "../imports/Login"
```

Is there a better way that I can include all these imports in a single or two lines and not call  them manually like this? I tried creating a `complete.js` file that contains copy pasted code as above then try to import that complete.js but it does not seem to work. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index file to re-export and simplify the import.

```js
// imports/index.js
export { Customers } from 'Customer'
export { Search } from 'Search'
export { PostComment } from 'PostComment'
export { Feedback } from 'Feedback'
export { Login } from 'Login'

// test.cy.js
import { Customers, Search, PostComment, Feedback, Login } from '../imports'
```

Comment: I tried to use the Login in test.cy.js, it tells me that it is undefined.

Comment: I noticed that the original exported files have a specific export declaration. I needed to alias that to make it work on my end. e.g. `export { all as Login } from 'Login'`

Answer (score 1):

To convert `default` exports in the individual files to `named` exports in the barrel index

```js
export { * as Customers } from 'Customer'
export { * as Search } from 'Search'
export { * as PostComment } from 'PostComment'
export { * as Feedback } from 'Feedback'
export { * as Login } from 'Login'
```